# Can I use function pointers to static functions like function pointers to non-static functions?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Can I use pointers to static functions like pointers to non-static functions?

Lets say I have:

```
void (*fp_some_event_handler)(void);

void KeyEventHandler(void){
    // not static
}

static void KeyEventHandlerStatic(void){
    // static
}
```

**Can I use static function pointer just like non-static?**

```
void main() {

    // now I have something like this
    fp_some_event_handler = KeyEventHandler;
    
    // and I want to change some function to static and end with this
    fp_some_event_handler = KeyEventHandlerStatic;
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a function is `static` is not part of its type but is instead a **storage class specifier**.

So you can assign either of the two functions in your sample code to the function pointer `fp_some_event_handler`.

Comment: OK. So can I expect that I will be able to call it from outside (static function call by non-static pointer)?

Comment: @Kamil Yes, you can call it from outside using the function pointer.  The `static` keyword just prevents the function from being referenced *by that name* outside of its translation unit.